# Access data from autocomplete search form

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

My autocomplete form works fine ie. it completes data correctly. Now I want that data to be accessible -> link me to a valid url.
I tried to make it work on my own but I came to a wall.

Can somebody please give me a hint or a link for working example.
Thank you for your time.

views.py

```
def paper_autocompleate(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        q = request.GET.get('term', '')
        autoPaperwork = Paperwork.objects.filter(
    Q(title__icontains=q) | Q(description__icontains=q))[:10]
        results = []
        for p in autoPaperwork:
            p_json = {}
            p_json = p.title
            results.append(p_json)
        data = json.dumps(results)
    else:
        data = 'fail'
    mimetype = 'application/json'
    return HttpResponse(data, mimetype)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('', 
    url(r'^api/paper_autocompleate/', 'papers.views.paper_autocompleate', name='paper_autocompleate')
)
```

JQAuto.js

```
$(function() {
  $("#autoPaperwork").autocomplete({
    source: "/api/paper_autocompleate/",
    minLength: 2,
  });
});
```

index.html

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <input id="autoPaperwork">
</div>
```

Comment: can you show what your view paper_autocomplete returns? is it properly formed JSON list? i.e. ["results 1", "result 2"]

Comment: yes. it returns properly formed JSON list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not tested but I think you need to do this:

```
def paper_autocompleate(request):
if request.is_ajax():
    q = request.GET.get('term', '')
    autoPaperwork = Paperwork.objects.filter(
Q(title__icontains=q) | Q(description__icontains=q))[:10]
    results = []
    for p in autoPaperwork:
        results.append(p.title)
    data = json.dumps(results)
else:
    data = 'fail'
mimetype = 'application/json'
return HttpResponse(data, content-type=mimetype)
```

not sure what your `p_json` was doing, but my JQuery-UI autocomplete works via jsut a simply json list of

```
["result 1", "result 2"]
```

which I get by using `json.dumps(<python_list_object>)`

edit: here is my code for a generic get sorted autocompete of any db object field

```
obj = apps.get_model(app_label=app_name, model_name=model_name)
#obj = locate('LessonApp.models.%s' % otype) # old way of locating
try:
    search_list = list(obj.objects.\
                       exclude(Q(**{field: ''}) | Q(**{'{0}__isnull'.format(field): True})).\
                       values_list(field, flat=True).distinct().order_by(field))
    if q:
        search_list = filter(lambda s: s[:len(q)].lower() == q.lower(), search_list)  # search the list for q, ignore case
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(search_list), content_type='application/json')
except Exception as ex:
    return HttpResponse('{"result": "error", "error": "DB Error\n%s"}' % ex, content_type='application/json')
```

EDIT: here is my javascript to call my input

```
$('#id_group_name').autocomplete({
            source: "/autocomplete/cec_cms/CmsNews/group_name",
            minLength: 0,
            delay: 500 //default is 300
        }).focus(function() {
            $(this).autocomplete('search', $(this).val());
        });
```

Comment: thanks for your answer I tested it. it returns properly formed JSON list but I still can't  access it ie. link me to a valid url

Comment: try copy and paste the result from your source URL, substituing for the URL in the jquery call to see if it works with the result. You may also want to put the code in the $(document).ready(function(){..}) call.  Your script might be getting called before the selector is loaded.